# What are the conditions under which a short read/write can occur?

Tags: c, posix, signals

The `read` and `write` functions (and relatives like `send`, `recv`, `readv`, ...) can return a number of bytes less than the requested read/write length if interrupted by a signal (under certain circumstances), and perhaps in other cases too. Is there a well-defined set of conditions for when this can happen, or is it largely up to the implementation? Here are some particular questions I'm interested in the answers to:

- If a signal handler is non-interrupting (`SA_RESTART`) that will cause IO operations interrupted before any data is transferred to be restarted after the signal handler returns. But if a partial read/write has already occurred and the signal handler is non-interrupting, will the syscall return immediately with the partial length, or will it be resumed attempting to read/write the remainder?
- Obviously read functions can return short reads on network, pipe, and terminal file descriptors when less data than the requested amount is available. But can write functions return short writes in these cases due to limited buffer size, or will they block until all the data can be written?

I'd be interested in all three of standards-required, common, and Linux-specific behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question : write can return short writes for a limited buffer size if it is non-blocking

Comment: If it's blocking, though, is there a guarantee that it won't return short writes? (unless caused by a signal)

Comment: @R.. i don't think is guaranteed. If i'm not going wrong there are other situations in which a write could fail: for example if the network card is removed while the OS is writing out some datas.. I think that even in that situation write should return short bytes. Don't sure about that. I'd have to check my network code that i haven't with me right now.

Answer (score 1):

There's at least one standard condition that can cause write on a regular file to return a short size:

> If a write() requests that more bytes
>   be written than there is room for (for
>   example, [XSI]   the file size limit
>   of the process or  the physical end of
>   a medium), only as many bytes as there
>   is room for shall be written. For
>   example, suppose there is space for 20
>   bytes more in a file before reaching a
>   limit. A write of 512 bytes will
>   return 20. The next write of a
>   non-zero number of bytes would give a
>   failure return (except as noted
>   below).