# Read/write alternately in subprocess stdout/stdin

Tags: c, linux, pipe, stdio

I have two executable. The first one (target) print data to stdout, read data from stdin and print another data to stdout. The second one (wrapper) is a wrapper of the first one. It forks, it changes child stdin and stdout then execute target.

I want that wrapper gets target's stdout, print it, send data to target's stdin and get last target's data. But the command block without printing anything.

The target code (I have one constraint, I can't modify this code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char buffer[0x100] = { 0 };

  printf("First line\n");
  printf("Input:");
  scanf("%s", buffer);
  printf("Last line\n");

  return 0;
}
```

The wrapper code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define READING_IDX 0
#define READING_IDX 0
#define WRITING_IDX 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[]){
  pid_t         pid = 0;
  int           pipeStdin[2] = {0};
  int           pipeStdout[2] = {0};
  char      buffer[1024] = {0};
  int       ret = 0;

  if (pipe(pipeStdout) == -1){
    perror("pipe");
    return 1;
  }

  if (pipe(pipeStdin) == -1){
    perror("pipe");
    return 1;
  }

  if ((pid = fork()) == -1){
    perror("fork");
    return 1;
  }
  else if (pid == 0){
    close(pipeStdin[WRITING_IDX]);
    close(pipeStdout[READING_IDX]);

    if (dup2(
      pipeStdin[READING_IDX], 
      STDIN_FILENO
    ) == -1){
      perror("dup2");
      return 1;
    }
    if (dup2(
      pipeStdout[WRITING_IDX],
      STDOUT_FILENO
    ) == -1){
      perror("dup2");
      return 1;
    }

    if (execve(
      "./target",
      argv + 1,
      env
    ) == -1){
      perror("execve");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  else{
    close(pipeStdin[READING_IDX]);
    close(pipeStdout[WRITING_IDX]);

    ret = read(
      pipeStdout[READING_IDX],
      buffer,
      1023);
    if(ret == -1){
      perror("read");
      return 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", ret);
    buffer[ret] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    ret = write(
      pipeStdin[WRITING_IDX],
      "Response\n",
      sizeof("Response\n")
    );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I build this two executable with:

```
gcc -o target target.c && gcc -o wrapper wrapper.c
```

Thanks to any help.

```
I see that child process block at read syscall. I think it is at the scanf line. But target does not write any data. 
The strace logs: 


>! execve("./wrapper", ["./wrapper"], 0x7ffca81b4f78 /* 50 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55bc56890000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=310009, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 310009, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f28eaf36000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260A\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1820400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f28eaf34000
mmap(NULL, 1832960, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f28ead74000
mprotect(0x7f28ead96000, 1654784, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f28ead96000, 1339392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7f28ead96000
mmap(0x7f28eaedd000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x169000) = 0x7f28eaedd000
mmap(0x7f28eaf2a000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b5000) = 0x7f28eaf2a000
mmap(0x7f28eaf30000, 14336, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f28eaf30000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f28eaf35500) = 0
mprotect(0x7f28eaf2a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55bc55a1b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f28eafa9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f28eaf36000, 310009)          = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f28eaf357d0) = 13384
strace: Process 13384 attached
[pid 13383] close(5 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13384] close(6 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13383] <... close resumed> )       = 0
[pid 13384] <... close resumed> )       = 0
[pid 13383] close(4 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13384] close(3 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13383] <... close resumed> )       = 0
[pid 13384] <... close resumed> )       = 0
[pid 13383] read(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13384] dup2(5, 0)                  = 0
[pid 13384] dup2(4, 1)                  = 1
[pid 13384] execve("./target", [], 0x7ffec0e88de8 /* 50 vars */) = 0
[pid 13384] brk(NULL)                   = 0x5564da73c000
[pid 13384] access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
[pid 13384] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 13384] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=310009, ...}) = 0
[pid 13384] mmap(NULL, 310009, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbfc376b000
[pid 13384] close(3)                    = 0
[pid 13384] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 13384] read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260A\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
[pid 13384] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1820400, ...}) = 0
[pid 13384] mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbfc3769000
[pid 13384] mmap(NULL, 1832960, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbfc35a9000
[pid 13384] mprotect(0x7fbfc35cb000, 1654784, PROT_NONE) = 0
[pid 13384] mmap(0x7fbfc35cb000, 1339392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7fbfc35cb000
[pid 13384] mmap(0x7fbfc3712000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x169000) = 0x7fbfc3712000
[pid 13384] mmap(0x7fbfc375f000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b5000) = 0x7fbfc375f000
[pid 13384] mmap(0x7fbfc3765000, 14336, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbfc3765000
[pid 13384] close(3)                    = 0
[pid 13384] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fbfc376a500) = 0
[pid 13384] mprotect(0x7fbfc375f000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid 13384] mprotect(0x5564d8c2f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid 13384] mprotect(0x7fbfc37de000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
[pid 13384] munmap(0x7fbfc376b000, 310009) = 0
[pid 13384] fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid 13384] brk(NULL)                   = 0x5564da73c000
[pid 13384] brk(0x5564da75d000)         = 0x5564da75d000
[pid 13384] fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid 13384] read(0, kolk
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13383] <... read resumed> 0x7ffec0e888d0, 1023) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
[pid 13383] --- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
[pid 13383] read(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13384] <... read resumed> 0x5564da73d270, 4096) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
[pid 13384] --- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
[pid 13384] read(0,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13383] <... read resumed> 0x7ffec0e888d0, 1023) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
[pid 13384] <... read resumed> 0x5564da73d270, 4096) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
[pid 13383] --- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
[pid 13384] --- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
[pid 13383] read(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13384] read(0,
```

Comment: Are you sure the program `"./target"` is really the program shown in the question? Please [edit] your question and show the commands you use to build and run the programs. Note that `./target` is relative to the current working directory, which is not necessarily the same as the location of the wrapper program executable. Please add the `strace` output to your question instead of relying on external resources. BTW: Why do you pass `argv + 1` to `execve`? Normally, `argv[0]` should be the program name, i.e. `"./target"`.

Comment: Thanks to you response. I am sure that wrapper starts target. The two source code and two executable files are stored in same folder. 
target and wrapper are simplification of more complex program. But I need to solve this specific issue to advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with stdio buffering, and if you could modify the target, you would just do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char buffer[0x100] = { 0 };

  printf("First line\n");
  printf("Input:");
  fflush(stdout); // this is what you'd add
  scanf("%s", buffer);
  printf("Last line\n");

  return 0;
}
```

That is a bug in the target. Here's how it plays out:

`printf("First line\n");` - The text `First line\n` is put into the stdio's stdout buffer. Interactive programs have a TTY for stdout, and when that's the case, if stdio sees a `\n`, it flushes the stdout buffer. But you're writing into a pipe, so stdio doesn't buffer by line, but rather by some arbitrary size, e.g. 4096 bytes.

`printf("Input:");` - The text `Input:` is put into the stdio's stdout buffer. The buffer now contains 17 characters.

If `fflush(stdout);` is called, then newline or not - stdio will flush its stdout buffer to the system's stdout file descriptor, at which point it is written to the pipe.

but since the target doesn't call it:

`scanf("%s", buffer);` - The target blocks, waiting for input.

Control switches to the wrapper:

`read(pipeStdout[READING_IDX], buffer, 1023);` - Nothing has been yet written by the target to its stdout, so the wrappers stdin is empty. That means `read()` blocks until there's any input.

That's where your program hangs. If the target called `fflush()` then the pipe would have contained 17 characters and `read()` would have succeeded.

Unfortunately, adding [`setbuf(stdout, NULL)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf) to the wrapper doesn't work, because `execve(2)` destroys that buffer and creates a new one in the new process image.

On Linux, there's a program called [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) which fixes that. You can verify by running your wrapper as follows:

```
stdbuf -o 0 ./wrapper
```

Apparently the way `stdbuf` works is by running the sub-program with an `LD_PRELOAD` library that calls `setbuf(3)`.

I don't think it's reasonable to try and do that yourself, but since your question is tagged with `linux`, you can replace your

```
if (execve(
  "./target",
  argv + 1,
  env
) == -1){
  perror("execve");
  return 1;
}
```

with:

```
if (system("stdbuf -o 0 ./target") == -1){
  perror("system");
  return 1;
}
```

And that would workaround the bug in the target.

However, once you've done that, you'll get the following output:

```
17
First line
Input:
```

Whereas it should be:

```
17
First line
Input:
10
Last line
```

(10 being the length of `Response\n`).

I Assume that you want to interleave this interaction because the writes from the wrapper have to be related to the writes from the target.

But you wouldn't know when the target finished writing its part - it could stop writing due to scheduling, or because the pipe buffer is full, or because it just takes long to produce output.

You actually need a protocol between the wrapper and the target - something that signifies "end of message, like "roger that, over".

But given, again, that you can't change the target, for the purpose of this question we will have to assume that:

- There are only 3 operations (from the POV of the wrapper: read-write-read).
- All communication fits in all the buffers - the wrappers' read buffer (1023 bytes), the target's read buffer (0x100 bytes), the system's pipe buffer (usually 4096 bytes) and any of stdio's stdin buffers.
- Everything is happy and peachy, there are no [short reads or short writes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5442617).

Under these conditions, you just need to add the last read:

```
    ret = read(
        pipeStdout[READING_IDX],
        buffer,
        1023);
    if(ret == -1){
      perror("read");
      return 1;
    }
    printf("read ret: %d\n", ret);
    buffer[ret] = 0;
    printf("read buf: '%s'\n", buffer);
    ret = write(
        pipeStdin[WRITING_IDX],
        "Response\n",
        sizeof("Response\n")
        );
    ret = read(
        pipeStdout[READING_IDX],
        buffer,
        1023);
    if(ret == -1){
      perror("read");
      return 1;
    }
    printf("read ret: %d\n", ret);
    buffer[ret] = 0;
    printf("read buf: '%s'\n", buffer);
```

(I added `read buf` and `read ret` for clarity).